# Problem from the 2019 Brazil Math Olympiad: $ f \big( x f ( y ) + f ( x ) \big) + f \left( y ^ 2 \right) = f ( x ) + y f ( x + y ) $

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

The following functional equation problem:

> Determine all the functions $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ such that for any $ x , y \in \mathbb R $ it is true that:
> $$ f \big( x f ( y ) + f ( x ) \big) + f \left( y ^ 2 \right) = f ( x ) + y f ( x + y ) $$

This is the fourth problem from the university level paper here: https://www.obm.org.br/content/uploads/2019/11/Prova_Nivel_Universitario_OBM_2019.pdf

I am attaching an attempt in an answer (because would lengthen the description too much and which is good practice according to [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/))

Answer (score 4):

### Edit: Fully Solved

**This is my attempt at a solution and is partial (eventually resolves only in $\mathbb{Q}$)**:

Substituting $x=0$, $y=\beta$ and then $-\beta$, for $\beta$ any non zero real number, we get the equations:
$$f(f(0)) + f(\beta^2) = f(0) + \beta f(\beta)\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad.$$
$$f(f(0)) + f(\beta^2) = f(0) + -\beta f(-\beta)\quad \text{ subtracting, we get}$$
$$\implies f(-\beta) + f(\beta) = 0\quad \forall \beta \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}\tag{1}$$

---

Substituting $x=1$, $y=-1$,
$$f(f(-1)+f(1)) + f(1) = f(1) - f(0) \quad \quad \text{ and now using (1) with }\beta=1\text{, we get:}$$
$$f(0) = -f(0) \implies f(0) = 0 \tag{2}$$

---

Now with this knowledge if we substitute $x=0$, we have for any $y\in\mathbb{R}$:
$$f(y^2) = yf(y) \tag{3}$$

---

Also if we substitute $y=0$, with all this information, we obtain $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$,
$$f(f(x)) = f(x)\tag{4}$$

---

Now substitute $x=-\beta, y=\beta$ and we get for all $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$f(-\beta\cdot f(\beta)+f(-\beta)) + f(\beta^2) = f(-\beta)\quad \qquad \text{using (2)}$$
$$f((\beta+1)\cdot f(\beta)) = f(\beta^2) + f(\beta) = (\beta+1)\cdot f(\beta)\quad \text{using (1), (3)}$$
$$\text{Thus, }\qquad f((x+1)\cdot f(x)) = (x+1)\cdot f(x) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\tag{5}$$

---

Now put $y=x$, and we get $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ (also for $0$, but that's trivial),
$$f((x+1)\cdot f(x)) + f(x^2) = f(x) + xf(2x)$$
$$\implies (x+1)\cdot f(x) +xf(x) = f(x) + xf(2x)$$
$$\implies f(2x) = 2f(x) \tag{6}$$

---

**Earlier I went down the following route which resolves the problem in $\mathbb{Q}$. Feel free to skip ahead to the final solution section**

> Now you can establish by induction that this is true for all integer
> factors (not just $2$): briefly, if it is true for a factor of $k$
> (say $2$), then in the inductive step, using assumption $f(kx) =
> > kf(x)$, we reach a relation for $k+1$. We substitute $x=ky$:
> $$f(kyf(y)+f(ky)) + yf(y) = f(ky) + yf((k+1)\cdot y)$$ $$\implies
> > f(k\cdot((y+1)\cdot f(y))) + yf(y) = kf(y) + yf((k+1)\cdot y)$$
> $$\implies k\cdot((y+1)\cdot f(y)) + yf(y) = kf(y) + yf((k+1)\cdot y)
> > \qquad \text{using assumption and (5)}$$ $$\implies kyf(y) + kf(y) +
> > yf(y) = kf(y) + yf((k+1)\cdot y)$$ $$\implies f((k+1)\cdot y) =
> > (k+1)f(y)\qquad \text{ completing the induction}$$
>
> ---
>
> But this takes us nowhere in the real domain. We can resolve if the
> domain were $\mathbb{Q}$
>
> **Thus for rational numbers** (negatives are easily determined from $(1)$ so consider positives for now), **we would get, for $p, q\in
> > \mathbb{Z}^+$:** $$f\bigg(\frac{p}{q}\bigg) = f\bigg(p\cdot
> > \frac{1}{q}\bigg) = p\cdot f\bigg(\frac{1}{q}\bigg)\qquad \text{ and }
> > \qquad f(1) = f\bigg(q\cdot\frac{1}{q}\bigg) = q\cdot
> > f\bigg(\frac{1}{q}\bigg)$$ $$\implies f\bigg(\frac{p}{q}\bigg) =
> > \frac{p}{q}\cdot f(1)$$ Thus assuming $f(1)=c$, for rationals our
> solution would be $f(x) = cx\quad\forall x\in \mathbb{Q}$ and
> substituting we get possible values of $c$ as $0$ and $1$, yielding
> two solutions: $$f(x)=0 \quad\forall x\in \mathbb{Q}\qquad \text{ and
> > } f(x)=x\quad\forall x\in \mathbb{Q}$$

---

### Final Solution

(Ref @1-___-'s comment)
We can observe that this is a [Cauchy functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) by adding up the $x$ and $-x$ substitutions and use $(3)$ and $(6)$ to get:
$$f(x+y) + f(y-x) = f(2y)$$
Since we can independently pick any real pair of values for $x+y$ and $y-x$, we have that $$f(\alpha)+f(\beta)=f(\alpha+\beta)\quad \forall\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$$

Now we can use this to target the original relation which now simplifies to:
$$f(xf(y)) + f(f(x)) + f(y^2) = f(x) + yf(x) + yf(y)$$
Using $(3)$ and $(4)$,
$$f(xf(y)) = yf(x)$$
Now substituting $x=1$, we get for all real $y$:
$$f(f(y)) = f(y) = y\cdot f(1)$$
Thus the solution is in the space of linear functions:
$$f(x) = c\cdot x$$
for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Plugging this form back into the original equation forces $c=0$ or $1$ and thus yields these two solutions in $\mathbb{R}$:
$$f(x)=0 \quad\forall x\in \mathbb{R}\qquad \text{ and } f(x)=x\quad\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: You should have been able to find $f(x+y)+f(y-x)=2f(y)$. Combining this with (6) and Cauchy Functional Equations replaces everything you did after (6). With that being said, your approach after (6) where you try to solve in rationals first does not usually extend to reals unless you have other conditions on $f(x)$ such as continuity. For problems at this level, you typically need to prove that $f(x)$ is a bijection.

Comment: Actually Cauchy Functions or additive functions did cross my mind - but as opposed to rationals where they promise linear function, in reals they need something extra also right? Monotonicity, boundedness etc otherwise can have many complicated solutions other than linear. So I did not consider that route. I now realize this helps in this problem. Correcting the solution

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach.

Clearly $f(x)=0$ satisfies the given equation.Let $f(x)$ not be $0$ everywhere.

$ Let \ P(x,y) \ denote\ the\ statement:\ \\ f \big( x f ( y ) + f ( x ) \big) + f \left( y ^ 2 \right) = f ( x ) + y f ( x + y )$

Then, plugging in $x=0 \ and \ y=0 $ gives

$
P(0,0) \Rightarrow f(f(0))=0 \tag{1} 
\\ P(0,f(0))\Rightarrow 
f(f(0))+f(f(0)^2)=f(0)+f(0)f(f(0)) \\$
$\qquad     f(f(0)^2)=f(0) \tag{2}$

Now,plugging in $x=f(0)\ and\ y=0$ and using $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get

$$ f\big (\ f(0)^2+f(f(0)) \ \big) +f \big(\ 0 \ \big)= f(f(0)) + 0*f(\ f(0)\ ) \\
\implies  f\big (\ f(0)^2 \ \big) +f \big(\ 0 \ \big)=0 $$
$\implies f(0)=0  \tag{3}$

Plugging in $x=0$ first and then $y=0$ after in our original equation, we get:

$$
P(x,0) \implies f \big(\ f(x)\ \big)=f(x) \tag{4}
$$

$$
P(0,y) \implies  f(y^2)=yf(y) \tag{5}
$$
Now we try to investigate at which points does $f(x)$ vanish.We propose that it vanishes only when $x=0.$
$
Lemma \ 1: f(k)=0 \implies k=0.\\
Proof:  P(x,k) \implies f(f(x))+f(k^2)=f(x)+ kf(x+k) \\
\implies  f(x) +kf(k)=f(x) +kf(x+k) \qquad using\ (4)\ and\ (5) \\
\implies 0=kf(x+k) \implies k=0 \ as \ f(x) \ isn't \ identically \ 0.\\$

$
\\ Lemma \ 2: f(x) \ is\ an\ odd\ function.\\
Proof:\ Note\ that\ if \ x=0,\ then\ f(x)=-f(-x)\\
Now\ assume\ that\ x \neq 0.\ Then\ using\ (5)\\
f(x^2)=xf(x)=-xf(-x)\\
\implies f(x)=-f(-x)\\
$

As $(4)$ suggests, $f(x)$ should be an identity function.But we haven't proved it yet.We have only proved that f maps a real number to itself if that number belongs to the image(or range) of $f$.Let $I$ denote the set of all values which $f(x)$ can take. Then
$\forall k \in\ I\ , \ f(k)=k.$ Note that if $k\in I$,then $-k\in I$ as $f$ is an odd function.After a thorough investigation of the elements in set $I$, we arrive at the following proposition:

$
Proposition: If \ \ k \in I \ and \ a \in \Bbb R \ such\ that\ f(a)=k .\ Then\ the\ following\ hold: \\
\bullet k \in I \\
\bullet -k \in I \\
\bullet k^2 \in I \\
\bullet k(1+a) \in I \\
\bullet k(1-a) \in I \\
\bullet k+a \in I \\
\bullet k-a \in I \\
Proof:\ f(a)=k \ , f(-a)=-k, \ f(k^2)= kf(k)=k^2 \\
P(a,-a) \implies f(k(1-a))+f(a^2)=k-af(0) \\
\implies f(k(1-a)) +af(a)=k \\
\implies f(k(1-a))=k(1-a)\\
Hence\ k(1-a) \in I\\
as\ k(1-a) \in I,\ so\ (-k)(1-(-a))\in I\ (as\ f(-a)=-k)\\
\implies (-k)(1+a)\in I\\
\implies\ k(1+a)\in I\\
P(a,k)\implies f(k(1+a))+f(k^2)=k+kf(a+k)\\
\implies k(1+a)+k^2=k +kf(a+k),\ as \ (k(1+a),k^2\in I)\\
\implies kf(a+k)=k^2+ka
$

Now if $k=0$ then $a=0$, so both  $k+a \in I$ and $k-a \in I$ holds.So let's assume that $k\neq 0$.Then
$f(a+k)=k+a\\
Hence,\ k+a\in I\\
P(a,-k) \implies f(k(1-a))+f(k^2)=k-kf(a-k)\\
\implies k(1-a)+k^2=k+kf(k-a)\\
\implies f(k-a)=k-a\\
Hence\ k-a\in I.\\
Hence\ our\ proposition\ is\ true.
$

Note that from our proposition we can deduce that $-f(1)\in I \ and\ f(1)-1\in I$.Subtituting them in our original equation, we get:
$$
P(-f(1),f(1)-1)\implies f\big(\ -f(1)(f(1)-1)-f(1)\ \big)+f((f(1)-1)^2)=-f(1)+(f(1)-1)f(-1)\\
f(-f(1)^2)+(f(1)-1)^2=-f(1)-f(1)^2+f(1)\\ (as\ f(-1)=-f(1) \ and \ (f(1)-1)^2 \in I \ according\ to\ our\ proposition.)\\
Note\ that\ as\ f(1)^2 \in I ,so\ -f(1)^2 \in I.\ Hence\\
-f(1)^2 +(f(1)-1)^2=-f(1)^2\\
\implies f(1)=1\\
so f(-1)=-1\
$$

Note that $f(x)-x$ should be zero.So in order to get that expression we subtitute $y=-1$ in our original equation.So

$$
P(x,-1)\implies f(f(x)-x)+1=f(x)-f(x-1)\\
as\ f(x)-x\in I\ so\ we\ get,\\
f(x)-x+1=f(x)-f(x-1)\\
\implies f(x-1)=x-1\\
\implies f(x)=x
$$

Therefore $f(x)=x \ \ \forall x\in \Bbb R$
or $ f(x)=0 \ \ \forall x\in \Bbb R$